# Why QString::toInt() receives a pointer and not a reference?

Tags: c++, qt

QString has a few methods such as toInt(), toLong(), etc.

These methods receive a pointer to bool that determines if the conversion was successful as shown here:

```
int QString::toInt(bool * ok = 0, int base = 10) const
```

My question is:

Why is 'ok' a pointer and not a reference?

I know it could be implemented using either, but I don't see any advantage of using a pointer over a reference.

Comment: a reference can't refer to nothing while a pointer can point to null

Comment: @vu1p3n0x But why would that be better on this case?

Comment: Try to implement using lvalue reference and you will understand.

Comment: @user7432759 [You could have looked at the Qt docs and function declaration](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toInt) to infer why they use a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know it could be implemented using either, but I don't see any advantage of using a pointer over a reference.

You could use a reference also with a default value with

```
int QString::toInt(bool& ok = some_bool_guaranteed_by_the_library,
                   int base = 10) const;
```

The downside of this is that the library has to provide `some_bool_guaranteed_by_the_library` as a globally available `bool` object. It sounds like the designers of the library did not see enough benefits to provide such an object.

Comment: Providing such an object will have an array of downsides on its own, which I outlined in my answer edit. Overall, I'd say in this particular aspect Qt provides the most efficient solution, whose only limitation is only due to C++'s lack of support for null references.

Comment: @dtech there is no lack of support for null references, they are not supported by design. You can simulate nullptr by providing special library provided `bool`, but providing such value when user need to pass different value for `base` is convoluted.

Comment: @Slava I think that "by design" is implied, since I talk about the language itself, not about any particular compiler or runtime implementation.

Answer (score 5):

In C++ it is mandatory that references refer to something. There is no null reference check, so it cannot be an optional parameter with a default null value, as it is with a pointer, which can be null, and can be checked to determine whether it should be used or not.

They could have used a reference if they made an overload of the function with different parameters. But this is easier and more straightforward.

EDIT: As R Sahu noted, it is indeed possible to provide a default value for a reference parameter. However, this can lead to several overheads:

- best case scenario, the default bool will end up being set every time, regardless whether you actually pass one. This could end up occupying a whole line cache, wasting like 64 bytes of precious L1 cache over nothing
- worse case scenario, the default bool will not be cached, which would require a RAM access, which will take a lot of CPU cycles before that data reaches a register
- worst case scenario, that memory will happened to be paged, god forbid on mechanical storage, which will take tremendously more than the previous scenario
- additionally, in a multi-threaded scenario, which is very usual, this might require some basic synchronization, on the odd chance someone decides to use the default bool rather than a user provided one, which will require even more overhead, even in the cases where the usage scenario is thread safe

Granted, this penalty might get masked out to a certain extent because of the lack of need to read it. But it will still be there nonetheless and will take its toll. Which can be totally avoided by using a null pointer and simply omitting that access if the pointer is null. So the need to use the `&` operator is actually a small price to pay for avoiding all this.

Comment: I do not think described problems are real, lib can just compare address of passed `bool` to predefined one and treat it as null. Real issue is readability - it is clear from function signature for a reader why pointer is used.

Answer (score 0):

Using a pointer **with a default parameter** allows the user to just call `int res = QString::toInt()` with no parameters. This can be very tricky with references, you need several overloads of `toInt()`.

For the case the user is interested in if conversion was successful or using another base, the pointers are there ready for use.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is 'ok' a pointer and not a reference?

Because it is common practice to pass parameter by pointer if caller need to signal - do not use this parameter. So user of the library can understand how to skip using this parameter without any further explanation in documentation ie function signature is self documented.